# React Native "Show Inspector" reloads the app

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, layout-inspector

Toggling inspector ("Debug Menu" -> "Show Inspector", or `Cmd`+`i`) reloads the app which navigates to the home page and makes inspecting other views not possible.

After a bit of researching, looks like it's not the expected behaviour, but not much else.

Did anyone have this issue before?